# Is the bare infinitive a verb not conjugated acting as a verb?

Tags: sentence-construction

I've asked this question multiple times, and I hope I can clarify it here. One of my teachers told me: - Unlike the infinitive, the base form is a verb.

So, the bare infinitive, wich is the base form, is not an infinitive, but rather a verb not conjugated. Thanks.

Comment: To be clear, a teacher told you that the structure *[ "to" + infinitive ]* is not a verb?

Comment: to + infinitive is a form or structure. The infinitive form of a verb **is** bare. Don’t mind the mess in here. :)

Comment: Yes, a teacher told me that the structure [ "to" + infinitive ] is not a verb, it's an infinitive either as a noun or an adverb. While the base form was a verb. Something that only confused more, because, does that mean it's a verb?

Answer (score 2):

OP: **One of my teachers told me: *Unlike the infinitive, the base form is a verb.***
If this is an exact quote, then there is a misunderstanding about the concept of an infinitive and the nature of verbs.

All verbs are verbs. Verbs can be expressed in different forms. Infinitives express the infinitive form of a verb.

From [grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/blog/infinitives/):

> Infinitives are a special form of verbs that can be used as
> a noun, adjective, or adverb. They are usually made by adding the
> word *to* before the base verb, and they can be useful when discussing
> actions without actually doing the action, such as “I want **to
> go** home,” or “**To err** is human.”

In an early English course where these terms are being introduced, it may be correct to say:
*Unlike the base form, the infinitive form does not perform the regular functions of a standard verb in a sentence.*

This is accurate because the infinitive form belongs to a category of verbs that some classify as [verbals](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/english/verb/verbals-gerunds-infinitives-and-participles) which behave differently from standard verbs.   Verbals, by definition, are verbs that express action or a state of being, but they are never used alone as action words in sentences. They neither express tense, nor perform any of the typical functions of verbs that align with a subject or an object in a sentence. [Instead](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/verbals/), they operate as subjects, direct objects, subject complements, and objects of a preposition which are functions normally associated with nouns, adjectives, or adverbs.

OP: ***So, the bare infinitive, which is the base form, is not an infinitive, but rather a verb not conjugated.***
The bare infinitive is an infinitive. It would be more precise to describe the base form as the form of the verb that appears in a dictionary from which all conjugations are derived. The bare infinitive is the expression of the infinitive form without a preceding *to.* The two look exactly alike, but they do not function the same way in sentences because they display different aspects of the verb.

*So, the bare infinitive is indistinguishable from the base verb until it is used in a sentence to expresse the infinitive form of the verb.*

Sources:
[Verbals: Gerunds, Infinitives, and Participles](https://www.cliffsnotes.com/study-guides/english/verb/verbals-gerunds-infinitives-and-participles) from Cliffs notes
[Verbals: Definition & Examples](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/verbs/verbals/) from Grammar Book
[Infinitives](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/gerunds_participles_and_infinitives/infinitives.html) from Perdue University
[Bare Infinitives](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/630/bare-infinitive) from LangGeek
[Infinitives](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/infinitive/) from EF, Education First

Answer (score 1):

The bare infinitive is a form of the verb.  It is used in certain contexts, such as with some modal verbs, "He can *see* it".

In that sentence, the subordinate infinitive clause "see it" completes the matrix clause "He can ..."

The "to" infinitive is also a verb, it is used in different contexts. The word "to" acts as a subordinator, marking a subordinate clause, headed by the verb. "He wants to see it"

The matrix clause "He wants ..." is completed by the subordinate clause "see it" with the word "to" acting as a marker.  It is just a peculiarity of English that some constructions require the subordinator "to" and not others.

There really is no difference. In both cases, the infinitive clause "see it" is headed by the verb "see".

The infinitive is not modified for person or for tense, it doesn't conjugate in the way that finite verbs conjugate.

(Your confusion seems to be the based on the observation that (1) infinitive clauses marked by "to" can be a subject or object in a sentence "To see Mt Fuji is my dream." and (2) Nouns and noun phrases can also be subjects or objects. And making the incorrect conclusion (3) Therefore infinitive clauses are nouns. This is wrong logically and grammatically, but often causes confusion.)